# How to run a function in every page, every device

Tags: functions, cookies, code

I need to run a function on my Wordpress, on every page of the site you'll visit, on every device, and template used (PC, Tablet, Mobile, ...).

This function will check if a Cookie has been set. If yes, great, else, if you click a certain link, it will set that Cookie based on some parameters.

Comment: sounds like a job for javascript, enqueued in the footer.php for your theme.

Answer (score 3):

Generally functions hooked with `init` action will be available on every page and posts with in WordPress. it will immediately fire upon WP load. so maybe something like below will work.

```
function ao_check_cookie() {
 //Your code here.
}
add_action( 'init', 'ao_check_cookie' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_head` filter to get it done. This way you do not have to process it at the admin pages in the back-end with the `init` hook as @Abdul Rehman suggested.

Since you are dealing with cookies, make sure to add a low priority (i.e. 9) to ensure it is called at an early stage.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_cookie_check', 9);
function my_cookie_check() {
 // Your logic
}
```